# how do i get remote desktop or other services running on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xserver

I have just installed ubuntu 12.04 on a computer and would like to have it act as a server for remote desktop sessions and other services on my network.  How can I accomplish this.  I am also new to using ubuntu.  Formerly all windows user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xrdp .

xrdp: An open source remote desktop protocol(rdp) server.

Open your terminal :

```
apt-get install xrdp
```

After you download , you can connect from any computer to your server , by **remmina** if you are using ubuntu or remote desktop for windows by typing the ip and the password of your account.

Official site [Here](http://www.xrdp.org/)